# What URI scheme does Azure Blob Storage use?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I'm trying to load some data into Azure Synapse Analytics from Azure Blob Storage. My environment uses vnets to enhance security. I'm using this to create my data source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE mydatasrc

WITH ( TYPE = HADOOP, LOCATION = 'abfss://mystoragecontainer@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net',

CREDENTIAL = myMsiCred);
```

I'm trying to create the external table using:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myschema.myExternalTable (

<columns list>

) WITH (

LOCATION = '/path/to/folder',

DATA_SOURCE = mydatasrc,

FILE_FORMAT = myFormat,

REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,

REJECT_VALUE = 0 );
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error occurred while accessing HDFS: Java exception raised on call to
> HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java exception message: HdfsBridge::isDirExist
>
> - Unexpected error encountered checking whether directory exists or not: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is
>   not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403,
>   HEAD

I read somewhere that abfss is only used by adls gen2, and blob storage exclusively uses wasbs. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that `abfss` is the URI scheme used for ADLS Gen2 while `wasbs` is the URI scheme used for Blob Storage. They are different since they have slightly different semantics when handling folders I think.

Also, you probably need to make sure that you have the right permissions when accessing.