# CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT failing for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, polybase

I am attempting to export query results from Azure Synapse to Azure Blob Storage

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyDataSource WITH (
LOCATION='wasb://rpdm10-azuredw-upload@rpdm.blob.core.windows.net/', 
CREDENTIAL=MyCredential
)

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT MyFormat WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE=DELIMITEDTEXT, 
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (STRING_DELIMITER='"', FIELD_TERMINATOR=',', ENCODING='UTF8'),
    DATA_COMPRESSION='org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec'
)

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MyTable WITH (
   LOCATION='/tmp',
   DATA_SOURCE = MyDataSource,
   FILE_FORMAT = MyFormat
) AS SELECT * FROM mytable
```

But this gives the error

```
Msg 105005, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'wasb://rpdm10-azuredw-upload@rpdm.blob.core.windows.net/tmp' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.
```

I am sure the credentials are correct, as I've seen a different error when they are incorrect.

Everything I can check seems correct.  The storage account is

- Locally-redundant storage (LRS)
- Storage (general purpose v1)

The container `rpdm10-azuredw-upload` exists.  Within the container, a blob named `tmp/` exists, which should represent the pseudo-folder `tmp` (although it doesn't seem to matter what path I put for LOCATION).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is simple yet obscure. As noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922166/what-uri-scheme-does-azure-blob-storage-use)

> abfss is the URI scheme used for ADLS Gen2 while wasbs is the URI scheme used for Blob Storage

It sure would be nice if the error were more like "Invalid URI scheme".